# ANDROID - SDK Installation error

Tags: android, sdk, installation

I can't install completely Android SDK trought by SDK Manager. 
I tried with many versions (8.1,7.0,6.0). Everytime, the error display is the same  as below :

**[image: Error Message here !]**

So, I'm administrator, I have rights on the parent's folder.
I tried also to change the SDK's folder installation but nothing change.

Thank you

Comment: As you mentioned you tried changing SDK folder want to understand whether you changes in C or other than C drive?

Comment: In C by default it's was in C:\Users\MyUsers\AppData\Android\ and after I put directly in C:\SDK

Comment: ok then can you shift to some other drive? 2nd way uninstall and install fresh